# Determining Pythagorean Triples Of A Given Number

Tags: c, pythagorean

So school has started and I am a little rusty on my Coding, I went to my professor and according to him I am close, and I have inched even closer I believe, but I am stuck.

The assignment is mainly for us to understand how to use "Vi" in linux, with a small coding assignment going along with it so we can code in Vi.

This is what we need to do, ask the user for a positive number, once the positive number is given we need to determine all the Pythagorean Triples that are possible for numbers up to equal to the given number.

So far this is what I have...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, n;
    int count = 0;

    printf("Please Enter A Positive Integer: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    while (z <= n)
    {
        while (y < z)
        {
            while (x < y)
            {
                if (x * x + y * y == z * z)
                {
                    printf("%d: \t%d %d %d\n", ++count, x, y, z);
                }
                x += 1;
            }
            y += 1;
        }
        z += 1;
    }
```

Now if I enter anything 5 or higher I get a correct triple "3 4 5"

```
Please Enter A Positive Integer: 25
1:  3 4 5
```

But no matter how high I go this is as far as I get any tips?

Comment: Fix your indentation and it should be easier for you to find the bug.

Comment: That's one of the biggest issues I am having with Vi, indenting is a pain any tips on hot keys to correct the indentation?

Comment: @dwarduk This solved my problem!! I'm just confused about why I have to reset it to 0 every time, I would think that it would just continue to give me  3 4 5, 3 4 5, 3 4 5 because it would keep just going back to that triple I am obviously wrong, but can you explain in words possibly why I needed to reset the values?

Comment: @Baws Mayne: Try 'set ai sw=4' and 'set smartindent' and 'set tabstop=4' in your .vimrc It should not be a pain at all.

Comment: @BawsMayne: It's because the variables were increased by one afterwards.  So after (3,4,5) is printed, you then have x,y,z set to (4,4,5).  Because x and y aren't reset, they stay 2 and 1 less than z respectively (give or take 1 while the loops run), not finding any triples with other differences between x, y and z.

Comment: If that last comment isn't clear, [here's the output](http://pastebin.com/vJhjcpZ9) from a modified version of your program that logs the values as each loop falls through to its outer loop.  I hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset your values of x and y during each of your loops :).  What you have is roughly this:

```
for(z = 0; z <=n; z++)
    for(; y < z; y++)
        for(; x < y; x++)
```

Instead you need to reset x and y each time their loops are reached, so:

```
while(z <= n) {
    y = 0;
    while(y < z) {
        x = 0;
        //...
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not resetting `x` and `y` to `0` on subsequent iterations of the outer loops.  You might want to think about `for` loops instead of `while` loops.

```
for (z = 0; z <= n; z++)
{
    for (y = 0; y < z; y++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < y; x++)
        {
            if (x * x + y * y == z * z)
            {
                printf("%d: \t%d %d %d\n", ++count, x, y, z);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a little debugging. Add an else clause to your pythagorean test to see what values you're actually testing;

```
if (x * x + y * y == z *  {
    printf("%d: \t%d %d %d\n", ++count, x, y, z);
} else {
    printf("NOT PYTH: %d: \t%d %d %d\n", ++count, x, y, z);
}
```

This will lead you to your problem.